# Метрика accuracy в multi-label classification tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Что показывает в multi-label classification метрика accuracy?

```
model_lstm.add(Embedding(256, 250, input_length=640))
model_lstm.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(50))
model_lstm.add(Dense(12, activation='sigmoid'))

model_lstm.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', 'AUC'])
```

Показывает ли она процент верного определения каждой метки класса предсказаниях или решает верный/неверный весь набор меток классов целиком?

Answer (score 0):

Метрика accuracy в multi-label classification показывает процент верно предсказанных меток классов в целом. Она не учитывает, правильно ли предсказаны все метки классов для одного элемента данных, а сконцентрирована на общем проценте верно предсказанных меток для всех элементов данных в наборе.

Comment: Будет ли это утверждение верным?
Предположим, у нас есть набор данных с тремя метками классов: "A", "B" и "C".

    Верное предсказание: Если все три метки класса предсказаны верно (например, "A", "B", "C" для элемента данных, который на самом деле имеет эти метки), это засчитывается как одно верное предсказание.
    Неверное предсказание: Если хотя бы одна метка класса предсказана неверно (например, "A", "B", "D" для элемента данных, который на самом деле имеет метки "A", "B", "C"), это засчитывается как одно неверное предсказание.